# Using "Map" in Swift To Create Superset of Two Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode

Let's say I have two arrays:

```
let letterArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"...]
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...]
```

I want to combine the two arrays so that I would get an output of

```
["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5"]
```

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: 'Superset' would be something like: `["a", "b", ..., 1, 2, ... ]`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs3zipu0_Rxs12SequenceType_S_rFTxq__GVs12Zip2Sequencexq__) before map:

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

let result = zip(a, b).map { $0 + String($1) }

print(result) // => ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5"]
```

[You can try this code here.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/e39d7a194c16a68835620ca3986c395ff1a98e3338023b989a8154eae62bf713)

[`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs3zipu0_Rxs12SequenceType_S_rFTxq__GVs12Zip2Sequencexq__) produces a custom [`Zip2Sequence`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Zip2Sequence_Structure/index.html), which has a special implmentation of the [`SequenceType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html) protocol, so that it iterates pairs made from the two source collections.

Answer (score 7):

Actually you **can** do it using only `map`!

If the two sequences have the same size just `enumerate` and `map`:

```
let result = letterArray.enumerate().map { $0.element + String(numberArray[$0.index]) }
```

If you're not sure which one is larger and you wanna trim using the smaller just `flatMap` the undesired values away:

```
let result = letterArray.enumerate().flatMap {
    guard numberArray.count > $0.index else { return .None }
    return $0.element + String(numberArray[$0.index])
} as [String]
```

Comment: If you're going to flat map it anyway, you could just do that on the first pass. `let result: [String] = letterArray.enumerate().flatMap { guard numberArray.count > $0.index else { return .None } return $0.element + String(numberArray[$0.index]) }`

Comment: I would avoid this, it's rather unclear at first glance, and it's like twice as slow

Comment: @AMomchilov I won't argue about the clarity part. I wouldn't use it as well (I think zip + map is much more readable) but I just wanted to show it **is** possible to do it using only map.

Comment: Ah yes, I concede. It's a clever way :p. You could also map over the integers directly: `[0..<letterArray.count].map{ letterArray[$0] + numberArray[$0] }`

Answer (score 3):

### #1. Using `zip(_:_:)` to combine elements of an array of `String` with elements of an array of `Int` into a new array of `String`

With Swift 3, Swift Standard Library provides [`zip(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/1541125-zip) function. `zip(_:_:)` has the following declaration:

```
func zip<Sequence1, Sequence2>(_ sequence1: Sequence1, _ sequence2: Sequence2) -> Zip2Sequence<Sequence1, Sequence2> where Sequence1 : Sequence, Sequence2 : Sequence
```

> Creates a sequence of pairs built out of two underlying sequences.

---

In order to get a new array from a `Zip2Sequence` instance, you can use `Zip2Sequence`'s [`map(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/zip2sequence/1689354-map) method. The Playground code below that uses `map(_:)` combines your letter and number elements into a new array of `String`:

```
let letterArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

let zipSequence = zip(letterArray, numberArray)
let finalArray = zipSequence.map({ (tuple: (letter: String, number: Int)) -> String in
    return tuple.letter + String(tuple.number)
})

print(finalArray) // prints ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5"]
```

---

You can refactor the previous code with a much concise style:

```
let letterArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

let finalArray = zip(letterArray, numberArray).map { $0.0 + String($0.1) }

print(finalArray) // prints ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5"]
```

---

As an alternative to `map(_:)`, you can use `Zip2Sequence`'s [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/zip2sequence/2294725-reduce) method:

```
let letterArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

let zipSequence = zip(letterArray, numberArray)
let finalArray = zipSequence.reduce([]) { (partialResult: [String], tuple: (letter: String, number: Int)) -> [String] in
    return partialResult + [tuple.letter + String(tuple.number)]
}

print(finalArray) // prints ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5"]
```

---

### #2. Using an `Array` extension custom method to combine elements of an array of `String` with elements of an array of `Int` into a new array of `String`

If you don't want to use `zip(_:_:)`, you can create your own `Array` extension method in order to have the expected result. The Playground code below shows how to create it:

```
extension Array where Element == String {

    func mergeLettersWithNumbers(from numberArray: [Int]) -> [String] {
        var index = startIndex
        let iterator: AnyIterator<String> = AnyIterator {
            defer { index = self.index(index, offsetBy: 1) }
            guard index < self.endIndex, index < numberArray.endIndex else { return nil }
            return self[index] + String(numberArray[index])
        }
        return Array(iterator)
    }

}

let letterArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
let numberArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]

let newArray = letterArray.mergeLettersWithNumbers(from: numberArray)
print(newArray) // prints ["a1", "b2", "c3", "d4", "e5"]
```