# Iterating over multiple arrays in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, enumerate

I'm looking to basically match up two different arrays in Swift using the enumerated method. So if I have:

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let array2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
```

I need to return a new array that would read:

```
newArray = ["1. a1", "2. b2", "3. c3", "4. d4"]
```

How do I make an array like that?

Comment: Related: [Using “Map” in Swift To Create Superset of Two Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37532205/using-map-in-swift-to-create-superset-of-two-arrays)

Comment: It is not clear where the first digit is coming from. Is it `array2[i]` or the index? In other words, what should be the result when `array2` is `["p", "q", "r", "s"]`, `["p. ap", "q. bq", "r. cr", "s. ds"]` or `["1. ap", "2. bq", "3. cr", "4. ds"]`?

Comment: It would be the latter of the two examples you gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out with some help from a friend:

```
var newArray: [String] = []
    for (index, array1) in array1.enumerated() {
        newArray.append("\(index + 1). \(array1)(\(array2[index]))")
    }
    return newArray
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

You can use `zip` method for this:

```
let res = zip(array1, array2).map {"\($1). \($0)\($1)"}
```

Note that this approach repeats the item from `array2` at the beginning and at the end. If the number at the beginning is supposed to be an index, use this expression instead:

```
let res = zip(array1, array2).enumerated().map {"\($0+1). \($1.0)\($1.1)"}
```

Comment: I'm trying to explicitly use the enumerated method on this particular problem.

Comment: @tjcarney89 `enumerated()` by itself operates on a single sequence. `zip` takes two sequences, and merges them into one. You can use `enumerated` first, and then grab the index, and apply it to the second sequence, but it is error-prone in situations when the first sequence is longer than the second one.

Answer (score 0):

This Solve your problem

```
let array1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
let array2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
var newArray: [String] = []

for (index, element) in array1.enumerated() {
    newArray.append("\(array1[index]). \(array2[index])\(array1[index])")
}
```